# eclipse cannot set a breakpoint while debbuging (ARM)

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gdb, arm, breakpoints

I am trying to use eclipse + st-link v2 + openocd on windows to debug an ARM chip (stm32 Nucleo 103RB board). I am using the eclipse Openocd plugin that is configured like here in this tutorial:

http://gnuarmeclipse.livius.net/blog/openocd-debugging/

I am abble to load the compiled executable manually to the target without any problems by connecting to the openocd through telnet, so the code itself is fine for sure.

The problem I am facing is that when I start debbuging (I connect to the gdb) I am not abble to step through the code in eclipse, because all the buttons are grayed out.

[image]

I am just in the first line of main. The openocd console gives me this message:

```
monitor halt
Warning: the current language does not match this frame.
monitor halt
Continuing.
continue
Note: automatically using hardware breakpoints for read-only addresses.

Temporary breakpoint 2, main () at main.c:79
79      volatile uint32_t count, count_max = 3000000;
```

At this moment I can do nothing else than terminating the whole process.
I am struggling with this for a really long time, trying tio solve issue by issue. I hope this is the last one... I would aprichiate all help.

Comment: This seems to be a known eclipse bug. See https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/cdt-dev/msg28270.html.

Answer (score 1):

There is bug with CDT and the newer Eclipse versions (http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuarmeclipse/bugs/123/). I came across the same issue and solved it by downgrading to Eclipse Kepler.